# How can I chain promises and multiple asynchronous requests?

Tags: node.js

I'm requesting data from an api and then storing it to a database:

The database

```
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then((db)=>{
    let dbo = db.db("scraper");
    // This will be the api-response:
    dbo.collection("sold").insertOne(
       { item: "canvas", qty: 100, tags: ["cotton"], size: { h: 28, w: 35.5, uom: "cm" } }
    )
    db.close();
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
  });
```

The api

```
fetch(link, {headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}})
    .then(res =>  res.json()) // parse response as JSON (can be res.text() for plain response)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(util.inspect(response, {showHidden: false, depth: null, colors: true}));
        // This is where I'll be storing the data
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
```

I could just nest the fetch-response inside the MongoClient, but I would much rather start both requests and then, once they are both done, start a chain of promises. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start promises at the same time, you should try to use Promise.All.

Here is an example

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var promise2 = 42;
var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```